# Angular error response interceptor: how to pass response object to template?

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-scope, interceptor, angular-services

This is the factory I can include in any controller so they can listen for response errors:

```
app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($q, $injector) {
    return {
        responseError: function (res) {

            var $modal = $injector.get('$modal');

            if (res.status === 401) {

              var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'reLoginPanel',
                backdrop: true
              });
            }

            if (res.status === 403 || 404) {
                $scope.msg = res;
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'infoPanel',
                backdrop: true,

                resolve: {
                  msg: function () {
                    return $scope.msg;
                  }
                }
              });
            }

            return $q.reject(res);
        }
    };
});
 app.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
}]);
```

The two modal panels for each category of errors:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="reLoginPanel">
  <h1>Session expired</h1>
  <p style="word-break: break-all;white-space: normal;">
    To preserve unsaved data: Re-login with the following button. On Successful login close the new window and resume to this one. To close this message click outside this message box.
  </p>
  <div>  
    <form class="omb_loginForm" action="/auth/enticate/google" target="_blank" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in with Google</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</script>    

<script type="text/ng-template" id="infoPanel">
  <h1>Warning</h1>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
  <br>
  <p style="word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;">
    {{msg.data}}
  </p>
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: $scope is not defined
```

And the 'msg.data' is not accessible from the template side.

If I add $scope to the service:

```
 app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($scope, $q, $injector)...
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- AuthInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile
```

The panels open and close fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any scope :

```
app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($q, $modal) {
return {
    responseError: function (res) {

        if (res.status === 401) {

          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'reLoginPanel',
            backdrop: true
          });
        }

        if (res.status === 403 || 404) {
            var msg = res;
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'infoPanel',
            backdrop: true,
            controller : function($scope){
              //your controllers code
            }
            resolve: {
              msg: function () {
                return msg;
              }
            }
          });
        }

        return $q.reject(res);
    }
};
});
```

edited : added charlietfl's proposition
edited2 : added controller

Comment: also might look cleaner switching `$injector` with `$modal` as dependency

Comment: It is required to define the "scope:$scope,.." attribute of the "$modal.open(...)" method for the data to be visible on the template.

Comment: Not at all, but what your a missing is a controller for your modal.